# PaaS on top of Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rackspace, rackspace-cloud, cloud

This question may sound stupid and if it does I appologise.

Is it possible to build a service like PagodaBox (PHP PaaS) on top of a virtualised enviroment such as Rackspace Cloud or AWS EC2 etc? Or would you need to have a dedicated server environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The term PaaS means it's already 'cloud-based'; hence the 'aaS' part.

Comment: @1.618 I meant is it possible to build a Platform as a Service ontop of another cloud environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, Heroku, one of the largest PaaS providers, runs on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. The difference between a dedicated server and "cloud" comes down to minimum performance guarantees and max performance available, and thus economics and cost. If you pay for a dedicated server, you should know what IOPS, CPU, and RAM you've got to work with, at all times. With "cloud", you may have minimum performance guarantees, and you may also be able to pay for *more* performance, on an only-as-needed basis.